# How to pass text value to MFMailcomposeView Controller

Tags: swift3, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Hi guys faily newbie here tons to learn in IOS

I am using messageUI  and I want to pass a text value to MFmailComposeviewController

this is why I have try so far

```
  var userdata = String(txtUserEmail.Text)  

  let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()

  mail.setToRecipients([" \(userdata)"])
```

for somereason  when I enter a email address it does not show in the composer of course there are other parts to the code that I have not included on here. As the main problem is i am unable to pass this value to the setToRecipients([])

any support would be most welcome here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is txtUserEmail a UITextField?

If so declare your `userdata` like this:

```
let userdata = txtUserEmail.text
mail.setToRecipients(userdata!)
```

A UITextField.text (not "Text") already returns a string.

Comment: something so simple, yet not obvious at the time of coding God I feel so mmm, thanks, Alex,

Comment: You're welcome. If it fixed the problem could you please select my answer? Thank you